# How to read display resolution thorugh HDMI? DisplayCompat fine on AndroidTV directly, but not on an AndroidTV Stick

Tags: android, androidx, android-tv, hdmi, android-displaymanager

Since AndroidTV scales down the UI for UHD/4K resolution TV devices, DisplayMetrics always return 1920x1080 for these higher resolution devices.

One workaround is [DisplayCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/view/DisplayCompat):

*On many Android TV devices, Display.Mode may not report the accurate width and height because these devices do not have powerful enough graphics pipelines to run framework code at the same resolutions supported by their video pipelines. For these devices, there is no way for an app to determine, for example, whether or not the current display mode is 4k, or that the display supports switching to other 4k modes.*

```
DisplayCompat.getsupportedModes(context, display)
```

works fine on 4K TV devices with AndroidTV OS running on it. Here I get the real physical native resolution. Whenever I have a AndroidTV Stick (like Chromecast) also with AndroidTV OS running on it, the very same function returns again 1920x1080.

As Brian Lindahl pointed out [in his commit](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/6af7da26568024e627cfe3b392c2057eb33e101a):
*We've learned a lot about Android TV architecture in this area over
the last year and the original concept is flawed. HDMI offers no way
to determine what the 'native' mode is. In addition, the system
properties are dynamic based on the current display mode.*

How can I read screen resolution through HDMI? Or if it is still "flawed" when will it be fixed?

Comment: did you able to read the supported display resolutions? @Murat

Comment: @Min2 As described above on a Philips Android TV OS device it worked like a charme. Reading the resolution on a device without Android TV OS, instead an Android TV HDMI stick it did not work.